# Azure VM | SqlIaaSExtension.Service.exe has initiated the restart

Tags: sql, azure, api, windows-server-2016

Did anyone go through below error for an unscheduled reboot of DB server?
I have manual patching for the server but it got rebooted with below error in event viewer, any help or guidance will be appreciated, thanks

Message from event viewer:

> **The process C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server IaaS Agent\Bin\SqlIaaSExtension.Service.exe (MYAZUREVM) has initiated the restart of computer "MYAZUREVM" on behalf of user NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM for the following reason: Legacy API shutdown
>    Reason Code: 0x80070000
>    Shutdown Type: restart
>    Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Automated Patching needs to restart your machine**

just to add; we have update management set on the console for the DB server but it got rebooted with above error, sconfig is set to manual.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason how the server got restarted:

The server created using SQL 2016 image while creation process it was set any patches which are related to SQL will be installed during a particular day and time, I have rectified it.

To check go to azure portal > select the DB server > settings > Sql server Configurations > select pacthing.

here for reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sql/virtual-machines-windows-portal-sql-server-provision#automated-patching